# Motivation for the method of adjoining roots of polynomials

Tags: galois-theory, roots, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

In Galois theory we learned the standard method of adjoining a root of an irreducible polynomial. More precisely, we saw that if $K$ is a field and $f\in K[x]$ is irreducible then the field $K[x]/(f)$ contains a root of $f$ (namely $x+(f)$).

I understand the statement and proof of the theorem completely. But I am interested in the motivation behind this method as it seems very abstract and unintuitive even though it works. Could someone please explain what motivated this idea?

Comment: Are you familiar with the universal properties of polynomial and quotient rings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We observe that $K$ has no root of $f$, so we just let $x$ be a root (this corresponds to looking at $K[X]$). Well if $x$ needs to be a root then $f(x)$ better be $0$, so let's just quotient by $f(x)$ in order to make $f(x)=0$ (this corresponds to looking at $K[X]/(f)$).

Answer (score 1):

The proof speaks by itself. But, here some explanation.

Recall that if $f(x)$ is a polynomial in $k[x]$ where $k$ is a field, as $k[x]$ is a Unique factorization domain, there is a unique way to write $f(x)$ in their irreducible factors. So,  if we want to find a root of it, it is enough to study one irreducible factor, and we suppose then that $f(x)$ is irreducible. But, this implies that the ideal $(f(x))$ is maximal, so $k[x]/(f(x))$ is a field, that "have a root" for $f(x)$.

The idea behind this, is that in the quotient you will "kill" every term that is a factor of $f(x)$, so $f$ in $x$ will banish. In fact, if we denote $\bar{x}:=x+(f(x))$, we have that $f(X)\in \left(k[x]/(f(x))\right)[X]$ has $x$ as root just as we required.